# How to add an extra light to an existing light

Tags: electrical, wiring, light

I have a question that I think is really simple for you experts (naturally I'm a novice) so hopefully someone can help me out. I want to add an additional light to an existing light already installed in my basement about 10 feet away. At the existing fixture location, there is a 2-wire cable and 3-wire cable as shown in the attachment, and wired the same way. How is the proper way to connect a new light to the existing fixture. Is it as simple as me installing new 14-2 wire cable from a new light, and attaching to the neutral, hot (red), and ground wire at the existing fixture?  Any advise or confirmation is greatly appreciated. Thank you.
[image]

Comment: Which wires in the light box are connected to the existing light fixture?

Comment: Just like in the image, there are 2 wires on the existing light (Red and White). The red attaches to the 3 wire cable (red wire), and the white neutral goes to a pigtail with 3 neutral wires. It's literally exactly like the image.

Answer (score 3):

Great job for a first post!  Excellent diagram.

Yes, you can easily add another fixture in the manner you described, assuming it's a 15 amp circuit (which is likely), if a 20 amp circuit, you'd need 12/2. You got it right.

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Congrats also to do-it-yourself-help.com for updating their diagrams for 2011 Code.